# Getting disk size from ioctl call for veritas volume greater than 2TB

Tags: solaris, disk

What is the ioctl command  to get the disk size of vxvm volume that is greater than 2TB? (DKIOCGVTOC is working fine till the block count doesn't exceeds the 32 bit integer size limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VTOC cannot handle more than 2TiB volumes. You need to use [EFI labels](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/817-5093/disksconcepts-1.html#disksconcepts-14) to handle them.

You should use [efi_alloc_and_read](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5172/efi-alloc-and-read-3ext.html#scrolltoc) to get the EFI label.

Comment: thanks.. How to find whether the Vxvm disk is EFI labeled or not ?

Comment: efi_alloc_and_read should tell you: VT_EINVAL=no efi label found.

Comment: I have a 2.1 TB concat vxvm volume .. It seems to be SMI labeled.. Can a volume more than 2TB can be SMI labeled?